# Converts strings of binary to binary

Tags: python-3.x, binary, hex, ascii

I have a text file and a would like to read it in binary so I can transform its content into hexadecimal characters.

Then, I need to replace '20' by '0' and '80', 'e2', '8f' by '1'.

This would create a string of 0 and 1 (basically binary).

Finally, I need to convert this binary string into ascii characters.

I'm almost finish but I struggle with the last part:

```
import binascii
import sys

bin_file = 'TheMessage.txt'

with open(bin_file, 'rb') as file:
        file_content = file.read().hex()
        file_content = file_content.replace('20', '0').replace('80', '1').replace('e2', '1').replace('8f', '1')

    print(file_content)
    text_bin = binascii.a2b_uu(file_content)
```

The last line produces an error (I do not fully understand strings/hex/binary interpretation in python):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "binary_to_string.py", line 34, in <module>
    text_bin = binascii.a2b_uu(file_content)
binascii.Error: Trailing garbage
```

Could you give me a hand?

I'm working on this file: [blank_file](https://ctflearn.com/challenge/download/959)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this? Refer to comments for why I do what I did.

```
import binascii
import sys

bin_file = 'TheMessage.txt'

with open(bin_file, 'rb') as file:
        file_content = file.read().hex()
        file_content = file_content.replace('20', '0').replace('80', '1').replace('e2', '1').replace('8f', '1')

# First we must split the string into a list so we can get bytes easier.
bin_list = []
for i in range(0, len(file_content), 8): # 8 bits in a byte!
    bin_list.append(file_content[i:i+8])

message = ""
for binary_value in bin_list:
    binary_integer = int(binary_value, 2) # Convert the binary value to base2
    ascii_character = chr(binary_integer) # Convert integer to ascii value

    message+=ascii_character

print(message)
```

One thing I noticed while working with this is that using your solution/file, there are 2620 bits, and this does not divide into 8, so it can not properly become bytes.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to split in 8bits!

Thanks mate, this is what I was looking for.

Thanks also for the 2620bit remarks!

Comment: No problem dude :)